# Hide PHP works on POST request but not on GET

Tags: php, .htaccess, url

I put this in a file named .htaccess in my WWW-root:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(([A-Za-z0-9\-]+/)*[A-Za-z0-9\-]+)?$ $1.php
```

it works for POST request url such as:

```
www.mywebsite.com/insertData
```

it would be insertData.php if I don't hide the php extension. However, when it comes to GET request such as:

```
www.mywebsite.com/getData?email=test&id=12345
```

I get 404 Not Found error. The full GET request with .php works just fine

```
www.mywebsite.com/getData.php?email=test&id=12345
```

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So you want the QUERYSTRING to be appended

Try:

```
RewriteRule ^(([A-Za-z0-9\-]+/)*[A-Za-z0-9\-]+)?$ $1.php [L,QSA]
```

- L: Last (it'll stop processing rules after this rule matches)
- QSA:
  Query String Apend, just in case you've got something like ?id=12345